# Localhost redirected you too many times in laravel after log in

Tags: url, redirect, authentication, laravel-5.5, referrer

**Every time I login I get this error**. In my real estate website I want to redirect my users to login before adding properties and back to property add page. For this I have method **create in PropertiesController** as:

```
public function create()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $property_types = PropertyType::all();
        return view('frontend.properties.create' , ['property_types'=> $property_types ]);
    }
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

And a **middleware to redirect to referrer url after login**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My **login controller** is as follows:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
     protected $redirectTo ='/';        
    public function __construct()
    {
        session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
        $this->redirectTo = session()->get('url.intended');
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

After logging in I get `Localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing cookies.` I do not understand what's happening.

Comment: You have explain, your desired result and code but doesn't describe problem you are facing.So describe issue you are facing.

Comment: @hu7sy My issue is after login I get issue mentioned in title. I'll update my question . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#http-basic-authentication`.

You don't have to check explicitly auth in controller, simply use auth middle-ware in routes.

Example:

```
Route::get('addPropertyForm', ['uses'=>'Controller@function', 'middleware'=>['auth']]);
```

Comment: I'll add that to auth route. Will `Auth::check()` hamper the operation. I do not think this is the issue. Checking if user is logged in or not.